# When GET Collection of object with Api-Platform, why do I get no properties?

Tags: php, docker, symfony, api-platform.com

I use Symfony(6.3), Api-Platform (3.1.19) and PHP 8.2.

I have a simple Entity `TimeSerieCategory`.
This can be only be read with operations `Get` and `GetCollection`.
I don't use any groups in normalization_context, I can return all.

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
    ],
    security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_USER\')'
)]
#[ORM\Entity]
class TimeSerieCategory
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 50, nullable: false)]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 50)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private string $code = '';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCode(): string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My unit test works well!

```php
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/time_serie_categories')->toArray()[self::JSONLD_COLLECTION_CONTENT];
self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_OK);

$firstCategory = $response[0];

$this->assertTrue(isset($firstCategory['code']));
```

But in production, sometimes I receive a response like that with GET Collection:

```json
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/TimeSerieCategory",
    "@id": "\/api\/time_serie_categories",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:totalItems": 3,
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "\/api\/time_serie_categories\/1",
            "@type": "TimeSerieCategory"
        },
        {
            "@id": "\/api\/time_serie_categories\/2",
            "@type": "TimeSerieCategory"
        },
        {
            "@id": "\/api\/time_serie_categories\/3",
            "@type": "TimeSerieCategory"
        },
    ]
}
```

[Edit]

If I restart the docker service with `docker compose restart [service_name]`, it comes back with `Id` and `Code`.
If a re-deploy my project (new clean docker image), the problem still appears.

The `cache:clear` does not change anything.

Note: i have about 20 entities in this project, the problem is only for this one...  but this is the only one with only GET routes and without serialization groups.

Comment: Could you please give us more information about the versions of each layer (api-platform, symfony, php)? Does this happen on the same categories? Do you update the cache configuration? What is happening when your refresh cache on production?

Comment: If you're using ApiPlatform 3.2 and as this is only a readable resource, what happen when you temporary removed the Asserts?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section